# October CMS and navigation on current page

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am trying to get the basically the active class applied to the current page. As it goes, the builder plugin is setting the URL through:

`<a href="{{ detailsPage|page({ (detailsUrlParameter): attribute(record, detailsKeyColumn) }) }}">`

However I am new to October so I am not sure how to reference `this.page.id` in comparison to the url set above.

Basically I want this:

`{ set UrlParam = detailsPage|page({ (detailsUrlParameter): attribute(record, detailsKeyColumn) }
{% if this.page.id == UrlParam %} class="active" {% endif %}`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best debugging plugins out there for OctoberCMS is this: https://octobercms.com/plugin/davask-dump

That plugin makes connecting your twig templates to your database / php rendering a breeze.

After installing that plugin you can use `{{ d(variable) }}` instead of `{{ dd(variable) }}` and get more information on the array nests etc.

So I would do `{{ d(UrlParam) }}` and `{{ d(this.page.id) }}` in your twig template. See what the dump has to say about each of those variables. For clarity I do believe you need the % here `{**%** set 'variable' **%**}`.

I am also not a fan of the builder component and I use the PHP section on the page / partial pages. And establishing a class with the use function and access the data with `$this['variable']`. Maybe worth looking into here is a quick example:

```
Pluginauthor\Plugin\Models\Plugin;

function onStart() {
    $plugin = Pluggin::all();
    $this['plugin'] = $plugin;
}
```